# Knockout.js and jquerymobile's flipswitch: bound variable not being updated

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm trying to use the new flipswitch control of jquerymobile instead of the slider, but it has a strange behavior: "flipping" the switch doesn't make knockoutjs update values accordingly.
But calling .val() on the select element I get the right value as it should be from the visual state of the flipswitch.

I've made a demo on jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Dn3Fz/3/

```
    <select data-bind="value: Partecipating" id="switch" data-role="flipswitch">
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
    </select>
    <br>Value is: <span data-bind="text: Partecipating"></span>
```

As you can see, the normal dropdown menu, and the slider update the label, while the flipswitch doesn't.

I cannot understand if this is a bug in the flipswitch widget or in the library. Or something else.

Would appreciate some help in debugging and possibly solving this problem.
Thank you

Simone

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513767/bind-knockout-js-to-a-boolean-jquery-mobile-flip-switch-toggle

Comment: That's for the old slider widget... I have no problem with that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug of jquerymobile 1.4 beta